# Using regex_replace() to replace a string pattern

Tags: postgresql, regexp-replace

I am new to regex and postgre SQL. I am actually trying to to use regexp_replace() to remove all the texts other than Target1 and Target2. The output should look like Target1,Target2. I cant use regexp_matches() here because it may not be target1 and target 2 always, user can change it to any name that he wants. Could anyone help please ?

```
["Target1",{"position":{"top":"129px","left":"450px"}},"Target2",{"position":{"top":"250px","left":"453px"}}]
```

I tried to do this using JSONB. Object is as below,

```
{"Source1":["Target1",{"pos":{"top":"129px","left":"450px"}},"Target2",{"pos":{"top":"250px","left":"453px"}}]}
```

to get the result as,

[image]

code which i tried is,

```
with myjson (jsonval) as (
--selecting the JSONB respone string here
/*{"Sourc1":["Target1",{"pos":{"top":"129px","left":"450px"}},"Target2",{"pos":{"top":"250px","left":"453px"}}]}*/
),
jsonKeys as (
SELECT json_object_keys(jsonval) as custKey FROM myjson
)
,
jsonTable as (
select custKey, jsonval::json->custKey->>0
as custVal from jsonKeys t1, myjson t2

--I want to get custVal as Target1","Target2 here. 
)

select * from jsonTable
```

Comment: I tried to get this done using JSONB functions but couldn't do it. The JSON array can have any number of targets. That's why I used regexp here. @Abelisto

Comment: Please add some sample JSON also to get the proper answer. Also please explain how `Target1` and `Target2` is related to other objects you have mentioned in the JSON Output.

Comment: I have updated the question. Please check @AkhileshMishra